# Boot loop. Safe-mode stuck at fvevol.sys

Tags: windows-7, boot, troubleshooting, diagnostic, infinite-loop

One day, after creating a Linux bootable USB, I noticed that at start up I got an error message from avastui.exe "*The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005) Click Ok to close the application.*"

The creation of the bootable USB might have had nothing to do with it and was probably just a coincidence.

To fix the issue, I reinstalled Avast.

Later when I tried to install mirc, I got an error message that it could not complete the installation. I thought "hmm weird"...and restarted the computer.

At the "Windows starting" screen, it went back to restart, showing me the recovery menu screen.

I selected safe mode but it would still not start...but rather again restart and go back to the recovery menu.

I noticed during the drivers load list when attempting to start at safe mode, it stopped at `\windows\system32\drivers\Aswardisk.sys` before restarting (boot loop).

Another thing to note (in case this piece of info has any relevance) is a momentary, split second flicker of BSOD right after the Windows starting screen before proceeding to restart.

**Things I've tried to remedy this issue:**

1. Last known configuration (advanced).
2. Startup repair through Windows 7 installation disc. (No restore
   points so couldn't do that).
3. Booted through Linux live USB and deleted the Avast folder in programs folder.
4. `chkdsk: c: /f /r`.
   Result shows 0 KB in bad sectors.
5. Renamed **aswardisk.sys** to **aswardisk.sysa**.
   Upon doing so, the drivers load list passed **aswardisk.sys** but then got stuck on another driver - **aswbidsh.sys**. So i did the same with that file.
   Again, it passed that file, but got stuck on another file called **aswbuniv.sys**.

   I continued this procedure with 2 more avast files - **aswRvrt.sys** and **aswVmm.sys.** But then it started to get stuck on non-Avast files, such as **disk.sys** and subsequently **classpnp.sys**. When I reached a file called **fvevol.sys**, renaming it did not result in safe mode passing/skipping the file like it did with the others, but rather go to a **Windows Boot Manager** screen like the 2nd screenshot [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/371318-failure-boot-fvevol-sys-corrupt.html).
6. `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=d:\ /offwindir=d:\windows`.
   Result says *"Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log."*

None of the above methods changed anything, obviously.

Could someone PLEASE help? Needless to say, I don't want to do a clean install because I need my files. Nor can I do a backup because I don't have a 2TB disk atm.

Thank you so much!

[Windows 7, 64]

Comment: Look also for error messages in the Event Viewer. Please post the file `CBS.log`. If you have `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump`, post one or more (requires admin).

Comment: How can I make another log with only the corrupt files? I tried running `findstr /d:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt` but nothing happens.

Comment: Just copy the file somewhere like OneDrive and give us the public link. A large file like `.dmp` is better zipped with 7Zip.

Comment: @harrymc http://www.mediafire.com/file/paiak3vaah8i1wf/CBS.log/file

Answer (score -1):

Examination of `CBS.log` shows a problem with Windows Update.
Below are some steps you can do, but before starting take very good backups
of your data, perhaps up to taking a backup image of the disk.

**Step 1 : Check Windows**

From a Command Prompt (cmd) run as administrator enter the following commands:

```
sfc /scannow
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth           (Windows 10 only)
sfc /scannow
```

**Step 2 : Reinitialize Windows Update downloads**

Enter the following commands:

```
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
sc stop wuauserv
ren %windir%\softwaredistribution softwaredistribution.old
sc config wuauserv start= auto
sc start wuauserv
```

**Step 3 : Repeat**

Repeat the above steps a couple of times, rebooting before each one.
Sometimes this works where one run didn't.

**Step 4 : Upgrade Windows to itself**

Using a Windows 7 installation disc of the same Service Pack level as yours,
reinstall Windows, letting it upgrade itself.
If the installation does not find the existing Windows on disk,
this step has failed.

**Step 5 : Reinstall Windows from scratch**

This is the last option, born out of desperation.
While installing, use the opportunity to re-format
the hard disk in the non-quick way, to renew any failing magnetism on the disk
and to better detect bad sectors. This will take longer but will give better results.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't Dism for Windows 10. I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Absolutely - comment added. Can't you update to Windows 10, where more tools are available?

Comment: How? I don't want to risk losing my files.

Comment: You aren't supposed to lose them, although some applications will have trouble. You may protect yourself by taking an image backup of the system disk and create a boot restore disk, just in case. A good product is [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: That's the thing. I don't have a disk to back up to. Otherwise I would have clean installed a long time ago.

Comment: Are you using more than half of the total space on your hard disk?

Comment: Yes, I am using more than half.

Comment: Then I can't come up with any idea except getting a backup disk. Otherwise, a problem might cost you your data. In any case, no computer should work without backup, or you're just playing Russian roulette with your data.